# Using goto after a variable declaration at block scope in C

Tags: c, goto

I'm trying to better understand block scope in C and whether the standard provides any guarantees regarding popping stack elements upon exiting block scope that may have been pushed to the stack upon entering that scope. As an example, does jumping to a label outside of a block (which is just, well, jumping to a label in C, nothing special there) after having declared a variable within that block result in a corrupted stack?

Here's a contrived example, and if it helps to further define the question, assume `-O0`. My confusion is around whether `err2` is popped from the stack when the execution path that jumps to the `fatal` label is hit. Because labels are nothing special in C, I'd hypothesize that `err2` isn't popped from the stack, and that stack corruption would result.

```
void foo() 
{

    int err;
    if (err = baz()) {

        printf("error %i", err);
        int err2;
        if (err2 = another_thing())
            goto fatal;

    } 

    printf("done");
    return;

fatal:

    printf("there was a fatal error");

}
```

Comment: regarding: `int err2;
        if (err2 = another_thing())`  1) the if() is actually an assignment, and 2) err2 is not initialized (if code used '==' rather than '=')  Similar considerations exist for the statement: `if (err = baz())`

Comment: `popped from the stack` is highly platform dependent action. I would expect the compiler for a platform that allocates the memory for stack variables by some hardware "pop" and "push" actions would generate proper instructions before `goto fatal;` so that no "stack corruption" (another platform dependent behavior) will not happen.

Comment: Thanks @user3629249, regarding 1) `if` is actually a statement, `err = baz()` is an expression that happens to assign the return value of `baz()` to `err`. The statement `if` will evaluate the return value of the assignment, which in this case is the value of `err2` 2) there is no semantic difference between the code as written and `int err = baz(); if (err) {....`

Comment: "I'd hypothesize that err2 isn't ...  and that stack corruption would result." --> No, this code is well defined.

Comment: Thanks @chux - I'm curious to know *why* the code is well defined, as my (incorrect) hypothesis was that it wasn't well defined.

Comment: The issue isn't whether `err2` is popped from the stack after `goto` jumps to the label, the issue is whether you attempt to access `err2` after exiting the scope. Since you do not, the code is well defined. If however you attempted `printf("there was a fatal error: %d", err2);` - Undefined Behavior would result but since no modification of `err2` was attempted it is unlikely there would be any corruption.

Comment: Thanks @DavidC.Rankin, I see your point, but if `err2` isn't popped from the stack, how is there not stack corruption? This is arch dependent, but if `foo()` pops the stack into some registers upon exit, if `err2` was pushed to the stack but not popped before the function exited, incorrect values could be stored in those registers

Comment: NO, `err2` is declared local to the function, the function stack-frame is released for reuse when `foo()` returns. `err2` has *Automatic Storage Duration* See: [C11 Standard - 6.2.4 Storage durations of objects](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin do all compilers behave this way?

Comment: Yes, all conforming compilers do, see the link I added to the comment above.

Comment: Great, thanks @DavidC.Rankin, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not possible to answer for certain; however most compilers allocate all the memory for the function at once.

As a practical matter, if it's gone out of scope, accessing a pointer to it is a bad idea and otherwise you don't care. Even at `-O0`, the memory for an out-of-scope variable might be reused.

In no case will the local variables leak. The stack will not become imbalanced. There is nothing dangerous in the code in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah, not accessing a pointer to something that's out of scope definitely makes sense. In terms of stack corruption, I was thinking more along the lines of `foo()` being called repeatedly, and the stack growing ever so slowly larger indefinitely. Memory leak is a better term to describe what I was thinking about.

Comment: And as a follow-up, if it's not possible to answer for certain (compiler-dependent), for portable could would you recommend not using this pattern?

Comment: Thanks, copying DavidC.Rankin's comment on the original question here for anyone running across this as the accepted answer down the line and skimming over only the accepted answer and its comments. 
"err2 has Automatic Storage Duration See: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4"

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a stack based processor like x86 using GCC or MSVC, the stack space for all the locals, regardless of scope will be reserved on entry to the function `foo`. The the stack frame will be unrolled on exit reclaiming the stack space as expected regardless of how the exit was reached.

For C++ however the situation is different. Not quite your example, but if you jump over a constructor then the constructor will not have run however the compiler will still run the destructor which would cause a mess. Fortunately as pointed out by Joshua in the comments, the modern compilers detect this situation and will generate a compile time error to avoid this situation.

Comment: Thanks for the response - one follow-up clarification. In your example, is the guarantee of stack space for all locals being reserved upon function entry fulfilled by the processor, the compiler, or both? Given you're suggesting the behavior is different per processor/compiler, I'm guessing this isn't something that's specified in the C standard?

Comment: Actually in C++ jumping around constructors will reliably yield compiler errors. If we had a C++ tag on the question I'd downvote so you lucked out.

Comment: @Joshua, thanks updated the post. Years ago the compilers did not do this checking and I was not aware that they do now, though it is probably obvious given the flow control analysis they do. To share more, I now learned that gcc's -fpermissive flag will allow the old behavior with a warning rather than an error. I learn something new everyday.

Comment: @rambo, it is the compiler and the code that it generates that will dictate this. The details of how this is achieved might be processor dependent, but I am not aware of a compiler that does not do this though.